# Copy range of cells from Excel to body of email in Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

How can I copy a range of cells from Excel to the body of an email in Outlook using VBA?

I just need the content to be a body of the Outlook mail.

Comment: This answers the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29092999/pasting-an-excel-range-into-an-email-as-a-picture

Answer (score 2):

You can find a packaged solution here : http://www.rondebruin.nl/mail/folder1/mail4.htm

```
Sub Mail_Range()
'Working in 2000-2010
    Dim Source As Range
    Dim Dest As Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim TempFilePath As String
    Dim TempFileName As String
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim I As Long

    Set Source = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Source = Range("A1:K50").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Source Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The source is not a range or the sheet is protected, " & _
               "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set Dest = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)

    Source.Copy
    With Dest.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With

    TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
    TempFileName = "Range of " & wb.Name & " " _
                 & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")

    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        'You use Excel 2000-2003
        FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
    Else
        'You use Excel 2007-2010
        FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
    End If

    With Dest
        .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, _
                FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
        On Error Resume Next
        For I = 1 To 3
            .SendMail "ron@debruin.nl", _
                      "This is the Subject line"
            If Err.Number = 0 Then Exit For
        Next I
        On Error GoTo 0
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With

    'Delete the file you have send
    Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512351/pasting-formatted-excel-range-into-outlook-message) if it can help you.

I was looking for a solution to copy/paste multiple Excel 2007 cells into an Outlook mail body with VBA but neither a direct copy/paste, a `MsgBody.HTMLBody = Range.Text` or a clipboard (through DataObject) worked.
Then I fell on this previous solution and it solves my problem, hope this will help you too :)

Cheers!