# Pasting an Excel range into an email as a picture

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating an Outlook email from Excel (Office 2013). I want to paste a range of cells (C3:S52) into the email as a picture.

Below is the code I have so far. Where am I going wrong?

```
 Sub Button193_Click()
 '
 ' Button193_Click Macro
 '

 '
 ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
 ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
 Range("C3:S52").Select
 Selection.Copy
 End Sub
 Sub CreateMail()

 Dim objOutlook As Object
 Dim objMail As Object
 Dim rngTo As Range
 Dim rngSubject As Range
 Dim rngBody As Range
 Dim rngAttach As Range

 Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

 With ActiveSheet
 Set rngTo = .Range("E55")
 Set rngSubject = .Range("E56")
 Set rngBody = .Range("E57")
 End With

 With objMail
 .To = rngTo.Value
 .Subject = rngSubject.Value
 .Body = rngBody.Value
 .Display 'Instead of .Display, you can use .Send to send the email _
 or .Save to save a copy in the drafts folder
 End With

 Set objOutlook = Nothing
 Set objMail = Nothing
 Set rngTo = Nothing
 Set rngSubject = Nothing
 Set rngBody = Nothing
 Set rngAttach = Nothing

 End Sub
 Sub Button235_Click()
 '
 ' Button235_Click Macro
 '

 '
 ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
 ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
 Range("A1:M27").Select
 Selection.Copy
 End Sub
 Sub RunThemAll()

 Application.Run "Button193_Click"

 Application.Run "CreateMail"

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's a worked example, tested in Office 2010:

[image]

```
'Copy range of interest
Dim r As Range
Set r = Range("B2:D5")
r.Copy

'Open a new mail item
Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim outMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set outMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

'Get its Word editor
outMail.Display
Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
Set wordDoc = outMail.GetInspector.WordEditor

'To paste as picture
wordDoc.Range.PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture

'To paste as a table
'wordDoc.Range.PasteExcelTable LinkedToExcel:=False, WordFormatting:=False, RTF:=False
```

Result:

[image]

In the code above I used early binding to have access to autocomplete; to use this code you need to set references to the Microsoft Outlook and Microsoft Word object libraries: <kbd>Tools</kbd> > <kbd>References...</kbd> > set checkmarks like this:

[image]

Alternatively, you can forget about the references and use late binding, declaring all the Outlook and Word objects `As Object` instead of `As Outlook.Application` and `As Word.Document` etc.

---

Apparently you're having trouble implementing the above; the range pastes as a table rather than a picture in your email message. I have no explanation for why that would happen.

An alternative is then to paste as an image in Excel, and then cut and paste that image into your e-mail:

```
'Copy range of interest
Dim r As Range
Set r = Range("B2:D5")
r.Copy

'Paste as picture in sheet and cut immediately
Dim p As Picture
Set p = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste
p.Cut

'Open a new mail item
Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim outMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set outMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

'Get its Word editor
outMail.Display
Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
Set wordDoc = outMail.GetInspector.WordEditor

'Paste picture
wordDoc.Range.Paste
```

As pointed out by [WizzleWuzzle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3042785/wizzlewuzzle), there is also the option of using `PasteSpecial` instead of `PasteAndFormat` or `Paste`...

```
wordDoc.Range.PasteSpecial , , , , wdPasteBitmap
```

... but for some reason, the resulting image doesn't render as well. See how the lower table is kind of blurry:

[image]

Comment: Thank you - It is pasting it as a table and not a bitmap.

Comment: This code absolutely does pastes the range as an image: look at the screenshot of the result. What do you mean by "a bitmap"? Can you show us a screenshot of what you expect as a result?

Comment: Upload it to imgur.com and paste a link to it in your question.

Comment: I've uploaded the two versions - http://imgur.com/45BzqBQ and http://imgur.com/MD89e4R . The first one is what I want - the range pasted as a picture and the second is what I'm getting - HTML or as a table. I think the last piece of code should have the pastespecial command in it? I'm not sure though.

Comment: Have you heard of the PrtScn button? Please, for the sake of everyone's eyes, I implore you to use that instead of taking a picture of your screen using your camera -- that's just ridiculous! Anyhow, I don't know why the above wouldn't be working as expected; but I have edited my answer with an alternative solution.

Comment: Whoa cool stuff. Never knew `Inspector.WordEditor` can actually be bind to word and be a `Document` object. Up one.

Comment: Neither did I before I answered this question! My trick is to first declare the variable as variant, and while stepping through code in debug mode, look at what type it becomes. Then take a guess at what it binds to.

Comment: Use PasteSpecial instead:
`wordDoc.Range.PasteSpecial  , , , , wdPasteBitmap`

Comment: @WizzleWuzzle: Good observation, but see my expanded answer.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett odd, we are **not** seeing the blurriness with `PasteSpecial wdPasteBitmap`, but it **is blurry** when we use `PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture`, particularly with the SparkLines (which is the whole reason we have had to pursue this approach--SparkLines cells paste but are empty). And THANKS, by the way... I had to edit my original post many times, and by the time it was comprehensible the original "thank you" was gone.

Comment: I'm trying to get this to work using the example exactly as written and am not seeing ANYTHING in Outlook.  The email opens but nothing is displayed.  However, when I right click on it, I have the options to paste in there, so it obviously is on the clipboard, just not pasting into Outlook.  I am hoping to get this to work because I have charts I need to copy and paste as a picture with ranges in the same email body and have only gotten it working where it puts the ranges in there but not the pictures(they don't show up)

Comment: @MattE Strange. What version of Office are you using? I suggest you post a new question showing a MCVE to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett I found out it was because Macros were disabled by security policy for my company and it wasn't something I could change.  I figured out a workaround to copy and paste a range into a chart as a picture, resize the chart and then export it as a picture.  Then I could make the pictures a hidden attachment and use inline HTML to display everything that way.

Comment: Another user asks how change the size of the image pasted. Maybe you can help with that.

Comment: About pasting as table instead of image, check if you forgot to set reference to the Microsoft Word object library, that might be the reason.

Answer (score 1):

I am providing an alternative solution to the above problem as Outlook.MailItem.GetInspector.WordEditor does not work in some organizational environments.

For security purposes, the HTMLBody, HTMLEditor, Body and WordEditor properties all are subject to address-information security prompts because the body of a message often contains the sender's or other people's e-mail addresses. And, if Group Policy does not permit then these prompts do not come on-screen. In simple words, as a developer, you are bound to change your code, because neither registry changes can be made nor group policy can be modified.

Hence, if your code suddenly stopped working after migrating to Office 365 or for any other reasons, please refer to the code below. Comments have been added for easy understanding and implementation.

If you have administrative rights then try the registry changes given at below link:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/926512/information-for-administrators-about-e-mail-security-settings-in-outlo

However, as developer, I recommend a code that's rather compatible with all versions of Excel instead of making system changes because system changes will be required on each end user's machine as well.

Code Compatible: Excel 2003, Excel 2007, Excel 2010, Excel 2013, Excel 2016, Office 365

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub Create_Email(ByVal strTo As String, ByVal strSubject As String)


    Dim rngToPicture As Range
    Dim outlookApp As Object
    Dim Outmail As Object
    Dim strTempFilePath As String
    Dim strTempFileName As String

    'Name it anything, doesn't matter
    strTempFileName = "RangeAsPNG"

    'rngToPicture is defined as NAMED RANGE in the workbook, do modify this name before use
    Set rngToPicture = Range("rngToPicture")
    Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set Outmail = outlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    'Create an email
    With Outmail
        .To = strTo
        .Subject = strSubject

        'Create the range as a PNG file and store it in temp folder
        Call createPNG(rngToPicture, strTempFileName)

        'Embed the image in Outlook
        strTempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\" & strTempFileName & ".png"
        .Attachments.Add strTempFilePath, olByValue, 0

        'Change the HTML below to add Header (Dear John) or signature (Kind Regards) using newline tag (<br />)
        .HTMLBody = "<img src='cid:DashboardFile.png' style='border:0'>"


        .Display

    End With

    Set Outmail = Nothing
    Set outlookApp = Nothing
    Set rngToPicture = Nothing

End Sub

Sub createPNG(ByRef rngToPicture As Range, nameFile As String)

    Dim wksName As String

    wksName = rngToPicture.Parent.Name

    'Delete the existing PNG file of same name, if exists
    On Error Resume Next
        Kill Environ$("temp") & "\" & nameFile & ".png"
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Copy the range as picture
    rngToPicture.CopyPicture

    'Paste the picture in Chart area of same dimensions
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wksName).ChartObjects.Add(rngToPicture.Left, rngToPicture.Top, rngToPicture.Width, rngToPicture.Height)
        .Activate
        .Chart.Paste
        'Export the chart as PNG File to Temp folder
        .Chart.Export Environ$("temp") & "\" & nameFile & ".png", "PNG"
    End With
    Worksheets(wksName).ChartObjects(Worksheets(wksName).ChartObjects.Count).Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: This is a good method and the first I've found that made it clear how to include multiple images in the email. One comment: I had to replace `.HTMLBody = "<img src='cid:DashboardFile.png'...` with `.HTMLBody = "<img src='cid:" & strTempFileName & ".png'...` to work with the rest of your code. Then the line `.Attachments.Add` can be replicated for multiple images which can then be html tagged into the body.

Comment: How is it possible to remove the border from the image within the email?

Comment: @jainashish do you know?