# Pasting Multiple excel ranges as a picture in the same Outlook email

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

Here is the code I am using to copy over the ranges as well as open a new excel email.  I can get both to copy and paste over just fine, but my issue is that when the second picture pastes, it replaces the first picture as opposed to being pasted above it like I need it to. What am I doing wrong?

```
    Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
'Finds last Row of email report
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long


lRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
        After:=Range("A1"), _
        LookAt:=xlPart, _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
        MatchCase:=False).row

'Copy range of interest
Dim r As Range
Set r = Sheets("Email").Range(Cells(8, "E"), Cells(lRow, "N"))
r.Copy

'Open a new mail item
Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim outMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set outMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With outMail
    .To = ""
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = shift_txtb2.Text & " " & "Finishing Report" & " " & Format(Now(), "MM/DD/YY")
    .HTMLBody = ""
    'Attachments.Add
    .Display
End With

''Get its Word editor
outMail.Display
Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
Set wordDoc = outMail.GetInspector.WordEditor

''To paste as picture
wordDoc.Range.PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture



Set r = Sheets("Email").Range("P8:T17")
r.Copy
wordDoc.Range.PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture

Unload Me
Sheets(1).Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38314574/pasting-two-excel-ranges-into-an-email-as-pictures

Answer (score 0):

Put this before pasting the second one:

```
 wordDoc.Content.InsertParagraphAfter
```

You can also try:

```
 wordDoc.Content.TypeParagraph
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work, though I do see where you're coming from. I moved that line around and tried it a few times in my code, but was getting the same results.

Comment: I gave you another option to try.

Comment: I'm not sure if I am running a different version of excel than you, but I was with that second option I was receiving a "method or member not found error"

Comment: The version of Excel shouldn't matter, as that method is a Word method. Open up Word and press the record macro button, then in your Word document, press `Enter` and then stop the macro recording. Go back to your VBA window and look at the code it created.