# VBA: How to avoid a date format change when Pasting an Excel Chart

Tags: vba, excel

I have created 5 graphs and tables that are uploaded to an Email thanks to this Question [Pasting an Excel range into an email as a picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29092999/pasting-an-excel-range-into-an-email-as-a-picture/29093857#29093857)

Unfortunately, my first graph has a change in the date's format when pasted in Excel already, whereas the second one (and all others) still look exactly similar to what I created. 
What other way are there to copy paste graphs or what should I look at to make sure this doesn t happen?.
First Graph with date as number
[image: First Graph with dates as numbers and second graph ok]

```
Sheets(2).ChartObjects(1).Chart.CopyPicture
    Dim p2 As Picture
    Set p2 = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste
```

'here date format changed

```
    Sheets(3).ChartObjects(1).Chart.CopyPicture
    Dim p3 As Picture
    Set p3 = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste
```

'here no change

Comment: Does that first image really get pasted as a picture? And does it still show up normally in excel? Even if you execute your code step by step?

Comment: Good point: No it doesn t. So not an Outlook problem (should I Edit my question?)

Comment: I think your problem is with your select statements. That is something you really should try to avoid. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba?rq=1

Comment: I am usually not using selections but I m not fit with Outlook vba yet. 
I deleted everything after "Set p2 = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste" 
And It gives the same wrong format in Excel (=Not a selection issue, I edited my Question)

Comment: You could try ´ActiveSheet.Pictures.PasteSpecial Format:=2´ or something like that. Maybe this helps

Comment: @Moosli I tried but cannot find what PasteSpecial to use properly (yours didn t work)

Comment: @Pierre44 see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-pastespecial-method-excel for the options. For bitmap it is `Format:=4`

Comment: @Pierre44 Can you try this once?
 "Sheets(1).ChartObjects(1).Chart.Parent.Copy ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste"

Comment: @Luuklag No Pastespecial format worked. Now I have tried with "record a macro", it worked the first time (without macro) then when I run the Macro it changes format again

Comment: @Moosli also didn t work.

Comment: when does the Dates change exactly? During the Copy or before?

Comment: Data changed while pasting. I solved my issue by pasting directly in Outlook (skipped "Dim p [...] set p [...] p.cut") but now the picture is not wrapped with text on top and bottom like others...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an answer from another website:

*"The date format problem happens because the axis formats are probably
linked to the source data. As long as the source data is in an open
workbook, Excel will go and find the format and apply it. To get around
this, before copying the chart, double click on the axis, select the
Number tab, and uncheck the Link to Source checkbox."*
Jon Peltier