# Pasting range into outlook as picture

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I have this code that I found on the web a long time ago (thank you Ron de Bruin) and have been using in many projects. I now need to modify so that it pastes the range in the outlook email as a picture. I am not an expert at all I just have been modifying VBA code to fit my projects. There is a lot of samples on how to paste as a picture but I can't seem to make it work.

```
Sub Email_Options()
Dim rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim Signature As String

Set rng = Nothing
' Only send the visible cells in the selection.

Set rng = Sheets("Closing Costs").Range("B50:E73")


If rng Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected. " & _
       vbNewLine & "Please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
Exit Sub
End If

With Application
.EnableEvents = False
.ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
With OutMail
.Display
End With
Signature = OutMail.HTMLBody
StrBody = "Loan Options: "

With OutMail
.Subject = "Loan Options (loanDepot) "
.HTMLBody = "<BODY style=font-size:12.5pt;font-family:Calibri>" & "</p>" & 
StrBody & RangetoHTML(rng) & Signature
.Display
End With

On Error GoTo 0

With Application
.EnableEvents = True
.ScreenUpdating = True
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' By Ron de Bruin.
Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TempFile As String
Dim TempWB As Workbook

TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

'Copy the range and create a new workbook to paste the data in
rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

'Publish the sheet to a htm file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With

'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
ts.Close
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", "align=left x:publishsource=")

'Close TempWB
TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

'Delete the htm file we used in this function
Kill TempFile

Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29093857/2727437

Comment: You could record the action with a macro and then check out the code that Excel generated, to find clues on how to proceed. I just did so and found that this the entire code to copy and paste a range as an image on the worksheet: `Range("A1:B2").Copy: Range("D3").Activate: ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste`  A small adjsutment to Outlook and it's done.

Comment: I did that but the problem is that I need to incorporate that into the existing function that does other things. I didn't write that function so don't know where to make the change.

Answer (score 0):

Updated the code:

```
Sub Email_Options()
Dim rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim Signature As String
Dim StrBody As String

Set rng = Nothing
' Only send the visible cells in the selection.

Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B17") 'You need to modify the "Sheet1" and Range"A1:B17"


If rng Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected. " & _
       vbNewLine & "Please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
Exit Sub
End If

With Application
.EnableEvents = False
.ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
With OutMail
.Display
End With
Signature = OutMail.HTMLBody
StrBody = "Loan Options: "

With OutMail
.Subject = "Loan Options (loanDepot) "
.HTMLBody = "<BODY style=font-size:12.5pt;font-family:Calibri>" & "</p>" & _
StrBody & RangetoHTML(rng) & Signature
.Display
End With

On Error GoTo 0

With Application
.EnableEvents = True
.ScreenUpdating = True
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' By Ron de Bruin.
Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TempFile As String
Dim TempWB As Workbook

TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

'Copy the range and create a new workbook to paste the data in
rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
TempWB.Activate
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    '.DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    '.DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

'Publish the sheet to a htm file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With

'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
ts.Close
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", "align=left x:publishsource=")

'Close TempWB
TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

'Delete the htm file we used in this function
Kill TempFile

Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Simon Li, thanks for the update but it did the exact same thing that my original code does. I need it to paste as a picture in Outlook nota as a table.

Comment: As I understand, you just would like to PASTING range into outlook as PICTURE(As your title mentioned). I getting some errors when I tested your code at first. After updated, then it works. I can copy my test table data of Excel into Outlook pane. Also, I've replied your question in MSDN forum as well.