# How to copy range of cells as bitmaps in email body?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have 7 different cell ranges I need to copy and paste as bitmap images in my e-mail body.

The ranges are E3, V29; e30, v54; e55, v80; e81 , v145; x3, af8; x9, af37; e3, v180

```
Sub Criaremail()

    Dim Outlook As Object
    Dim email As Object
    Dim xInspect As Object
    Dim pageEditor As Object

    assunto = Sheets("Corpo do Email").Range("AH1")
    para = Sheets("Corpo do Email").Range("AH2")

    Set Outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
    Set email = Outlook.CreateItem(0)

    With email
        .Display
        .Subject = assunto
        .To = para
        .Body = ""

    Set xInspect = email.GetInspector
    Set pageEditor = xInspect.WordEditor

    Sheets("Corpo do Email").Range("E3:V29").Copy

    pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start = Len(.Body)
    pageEditor.Application.Selection.End = 
    pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start
    pageEditor.Application.Selection.PasteSpecial (wdPasteBitmap)
    .Display

    Set pageEditor = Nothing
    Set xInspect = Nothing

    End With

    Set email = Nothing
    Set Outlook = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29092999/pasting-an-excel-range-into-an-email-as-a-picture

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pasting an Excel range into an email as a picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29092999/pasting-an-excel-range-into-an-email-as-a-picture)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either copy each of your 7 ranges individually or you loop over each area of a multirange.
I added two alternatives for pasting: Paste as chart or as bitmap.
With my code, you'll also retain your default email signature.

```
Sub Criaremail()

    Dim Outlook As Object
    Dim email As Object
    Dim xInspect As Object
    Dim pageEditor As Object
    Dim assunto As String, para As String
    Dim myRange As Excel.Range

    assunto = Sheets("Corpo do Email").Range("AH1")
    para = Sheets("Corpo do Email").Range("AH2")

    Set Outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
    Set email = Outlook.CreateItem(0)

    With email
        .Subject = assunto
        .To = para

        Set xInspect = email.GetInspector
        Set pageEditor = xInspect.WordEditor

        pageEditor.Range.Characters(1).Select
        With pageEditor.Application.Selection
            .Collapse 1                 ' 1 = wdCollapseStart
            .InsertAfter "Hi," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                     "here's the info:" & vbCrLf
            .Collapse 0                 ' 0 = wdCollapseEnd
            For Each myRange In Sheets("Corpo do Email") _
                .Range( _
                "E3:V29, E30:V54, E55:V80, E81:V145, X3:AF8, X9:AF37, E3:V180" _
                ).Areas
                myRange.Copy
                '.PasteAndFormat Type:=13       ' 13 = wdChartPicture
                .PasteSpecial DataType:=4       ' 4 = wdPasteBitmap
                .InsertParagraphAfter
                .Collapse 0
            Next myRange
            .InsertAfter "Best wishes,"
            .Collapse 0
        End With
        .Display

        Set pageEditor = Nothing
        Set xInspect = Nothing

    End With

    Set email = Nothing
    Set Outlook = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: How can I change this code to paste the picture as Bitmap and do it for 7 more different ranges in the same e-mail body?