# Copy Excel Range & Paste as picture in Outlook using VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

Here is the VBA code which I used to copy Excel range & paste it as picture in Outlook Email body. It used to work for me, but recently when I tried it after long gap of 1 year, I can see that macro is terminating on this line "doc.Range.PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture" without any error message.

Please help in identifying the issue.

```
Sub CopyExcelRangeToOutlookMail()

        
        Dim outlookApplication As Outlook.Application
        Dim mail As Outlook.MailItem
        Dim insp As Outlook.Inspector
        Dim doc As Word.Document
        Dim msgText As String
        Dim myCell1 As Range
        Dim To_List As String
        Dim myCell2 As Range
        Dim CC_List As String
        Dim myCell3 As Range
        Dim BCC_List As String
        
        Set outlookApplication = New Outlook.Application
        Set mail = outlookApplication.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        
            With mail
                     .BodyFormat = olFormatRichText
                     .Display
                     .To = To_List
                     .CC = CC_List
                     .BCC = BCC_List
                     .Subject = "Team wishes you Happy Birthday!"
                     Set insp = .GetInspector
                     Set doc = insp.WordEditor
                     
                    doc.Range.InsertBefore msgText
                    Sheet2.Range("A7:S51").Copy
                     
                    DoEvents
                    doc.Range.PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture    'macro terminating while trying to execute this line without error or result

                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End With

End Sub
```

Comment: The range I am trying to copy from excel is having picture in it

Comment: Do you have any problems when doing that manually in Word?

Comment: Also try to remove the `.BodyFormat = olFormatRichText` line from the code and see whether it helps.

Comment: Have you recently changed to Office365? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62163275/19353309) speaks of an issue from Office365 with a different solution.

Comment: @Notus_Panda ... No. I have been using Office 365 for quite some time

Comment: probably the picture was never copied. If there is only one picture on that sheet, try this: Application.ActiveSheet.Shapes.Item(1).Copy

Comment: Try `Sheet2.Range("A7:S51").CopyPicture` followed by a regular paste.