# Creating and copying Excel chart to Outlook works line by line but not when run

Tags: excel, vba, charts

When I run the code the chart is not created properly and it pastes a blank image into the email. When I step line by line it is fine.

```vb
Sub SendRangeScreenshotByEmail()
    ' Define variables
    Dim outlookApp As Object
    Dim outlookMail As Object
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim tempChart As ChartObject
    Dim base64Image As String

    ' Set the range to be captured
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SUM TREND").Range("A1:U34")

    ' Create a new chart sheet to paste the picture
    Set tempChart = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).ChartObjects.Add(Left:=10, Width:=1400, Top:=75, Height:=600)

    ' Copy the range as a picture to the chart
    rng.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    tempChart.chart.Paste

    ' Convert the chart to a Base64-encoded image
    base64Image = ChartToBase64(tempChart.chart)

    ' Create a new Outlook Application
    Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    ' Create a new email
    Set outlookMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(0)

    ' Add a subject and recipient
    outlookMail.Subject = "Screenshot of Range"
    outlookMail.To = "email@email.com"

    ' Attach the Excel file
    outlookMail.Attachments.Add ThisWorkbook.FullName

    ' Add the screenshot to the email body as an embedded image
    outlookMail.HTMLBody = "<p><img src='data:image/png;base64," & base64Image & "'></p>"

    ' Display the email
    outlookMail.Display

    ' Clean up (delete the temporary chart)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    tempChart.Delete
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
Function ChartToBase64(chart As chart) As String
    ' Convert chart image to Base64
    Dim tempChart As ChartObject
    Set tempChart = chart.Parent

    ' Export the chart area as a temporary image file
    Dim tempFilePath As String
    tempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\" & "ChartTempImage.png"
    tempChart.chart.Export Filename:=tempFilePath, FilterName:="PNG"

    ' Read the image file as Base64
    ChartToBase64 = FileToBase64(tempFilePath)

    ' Delete the temporary image file
    Kill tempFilePath
End Function


Function FileToBase64(filePath As String) As String
    ' Convert a file to Base64
    Dim objXML As Object
    Dim objNode As Object

    ' Read the file as binary and encode it to Base64
    Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
    objXML.Load (filePath)

    Set objNode = objXML.CreateElement("b64")
    objNode.DataType = "bin.base64"
    objNode.nodeTypedValue = GetBytes(filePath)
    
    FileToBase64 = objNode.Text
End Function

Function GetBytes(filePath As String) As Variant
    ' Read the file as binary
    Dim objStream As Object
    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

    objStream.Open
    objStream.Type = 1 ' Binary
    objStream.LoadFromFile filePath

    GetBytes = objStream.Read
    objStream.Close
End Function
```

I tried `Application.Wait` and `DoEvents` on various lines. I thought wait would work, because when I clicked through the code in step by step mode too fast it was making blank emails too.

When I put the wait after the line which makes the temp chart, it made the chart but looked like it was not loading properly, so I tried loops.

Comment: Try [pasting the range into the Word editor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29093857/4717755) instead and see how that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works consistently for me:

```
Sub SendRangeScreenshotByEmail()
    ' Define variables
    Dim outlookApp As Object
    Dim outlookMail As Object
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim tempChart As ChartObject
    Dim base64Image As String, t

    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SUM TREND").Range("A1:U34")
    'adding chart on same sheet...
    Set tempChart = rng.Worksheet.ChartObjects.Add( _
       Left:=rng.Left + rng.Width + 20, Width:=1400, Top:=10, Height:=600)
    rng.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

    t = Timer + 0.5     'add a 0.5 sec delay here
    Do While Timer < t
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    tempChart.chart.Paste
    base64Image = ChartToBase64(tempChart.chart)

    Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set outlookMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(0)
    outlookMail.Subject = "Screenshot of Range"
    outlookMail.To = "email@email.com"
    outlookMail.Attachments.Add ThisWorkbook.FullName
    outlookMail.HTMLBody = "<p><img src='data:image/png;base64," & base64Image & "'></p>"
    outlookMail.Display

    ' Clean up (delete the temporary chart)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    tempChart.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Without the delay I was getting the same blank emails...

Comment: Thank you very much! It has solved my problem! Only I had to have 1s instead of 0.5

Comment: Just additional information if someone has the same problem:
The temp chart has to be on the window, so you can see it, other case it cannot paste the image into it.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen similar faults using certain types of X-Y chart since XL2007 and you just have to work around them. There is a race condition somewhere that allows it to try and draw data points before the axis scaling is fully established. You have to put a small manual delay in just the right place to make it work.

One tell tale that it is a race condition is that it all works fine if you step through the code line by line but refuses to work at full speed. It takes VBA code to execute the steps quickly enough to cause trouble.

I'd try delays either side of rng.CopyPicture as a first guess. I suspect the Copy is occurring in parallel with the (slow) drawing. You may have to find the right position(s) and length(s) for these delays by trial and error (and then add a bit to allow for faster future machines if it is in regular use).