# How do I reference a cell that contains a FilePath for a photo i would like to embed onto email?

Tags: vba, email, path, photo

Hello there i'm trying to reference a cell that contains a File path for a JPG image I would like to include in my email as an embedment. How can this be done, thank you.

```
Sub SendSubTo_email()

    Set we = Sheets("Master_Tab")
    Dim PhotoFilePath As String
    PhotoFilePath = we.Range("J5")

    EmailItem.HTMLBody = img src=PhotoFilePath width='90%' height='90%'
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Looks like your HTML isn't formatted correctly.  However, you can't send a mail with an image tag linked to a file on your local PC - the image needs to be embedded in the mail.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77607120/my-vba-code-works-line-by-line-but-not-when-it-is-run/77607947#77607947 for a different approach.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My VBA code works line by line but not when it is run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77607120/my-vba-code-works-line-by-line-but-not-when-it-is-run)